# Freezes on Boot

Tags: boot, grub2, gparted

I'm trying to repair an issue that causes a freeze-up after a text dump that includes the line “Started Hold until boot process finishes up”.  I've booted from a USB stick and used Boot Repair, but haven't tried restarting yet.  The URL from that is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cDwfnCkBB9/

Looking at my GParted output, can you see anything likely to cause trouble?  I'll try the reboot now, but I'm not expecting good things.  Thanks.

[image: GParted image]

Comment: What did you get after the reboot?

Comment: Black screen, prompt and a big headache.